# Pascal XE giving "Access Violation at address 0074FC58" in module "Pascal.exe", Read Of Address 0624FF94'

Tags: windows, ide, pascal

I am using Pascal XE as my IDE in window 10. I can execute code there but it gave this error:

'Access Violation at address 0074FC58" in module "PascalXE.exe", Read Of Address 0624FF94'

whenever I hovered over the tool bar even in an empty project. I suspected it was the IDE causing trouble. I tried to reinstall it, and also tried to put PascalXE.exe in Window 10 Data Execution Prevention Tab. However both of these didn't work for me.

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the program in compatibility mode for Windows 7.

I just had this issue after installing a newer version of the program.  Funny, because I don't remember having this problem with the old version (although I hadn't really used it in quite a while).  I had to not only change to compatibility mode (win7) but also change the dpi settings (at the bottom of the compatibility tab) to "system", but that's probably because I'm running win10 at 4k res @ 175% scaling.  No more errors.